# NHibernate XML mapping throws Transaction Not Connected exception

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, nhibernate

I have a string field on my model that I serialize Xml to:

```
public virtual string XmlData { get; set; }
```

I have a corresponding column in my SQL Server table of type 'xml' and I'm mapping it in my hbm.xml file like this:

```
<property name="XmlData" type="StringClob">
  <column name="XmlData" sql-type="xml" />
</property>
```

When I try to save my model I get an NHibernate.TransactionException:

```
{"Transaction not connected, or was disconnected"}
```

The code I'm using to save:

```
    public void Save(T entity)
    {
        WithinTransaction(s => s.SaveOrUpdate(entity));
    }

    protected void WithinTransaction(Action<ISession> action)
    {
        var transaction = Session.BeginTransaction();
        try
        {
            action(Session);
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            transaction.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

I assume another error/exception is at fault, but the "Transaction not connected" exception is hiding the details.  There is no InnerException.

If I change the field type in the database and the sql-type in the mapping from 'xml' to 'text', then the whole thing works perfectly.  However I need the field to be of type 'xml'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include more details about the exception, like the stack trace, to allow better diagnostics.

Probably the `Rollback` fails, hiding the original exception. Rewrite your catch. At least check if the transaction is still ongoing:

```cs
catch
{
    if (transaction.IsActive)
        transaction.Rollback();
    throw;
}
```

Or for supporting worst cases, protect against any new exception:

```cs
catch
{
    try
    {
        if (transaction.IsActive)
            transaction.Rollback();
    }
    catch (Exception rollbackEx)
    {
        // Avoid hiding original exception, swallow rollback failures.
        // Better add some log though. (log4net example below, supposing
        // you have a ILog _logger property)
        _logger.Error(
             "Transaction rollback failure after a first exception, " +
                 "swallowing rollback failure",
             rollbackEx);
    }
    throw;
}
```

Now, why do you need to tell NHibernate the db type is `xml`? As far as I know, it is useful mainly for generating your db schema from mappings. Are you doing that? If not, does it works not telling anything to NHibernate about `xml` type in db, and just let it get handled as string by NHibernate, while having it as `xml` in DB?

Comment: Perfect! It was the rollback throwing an exception and hiding the original one.  I was then able to identify the actual cause was down to an encoding mismatch in the xml declaration and I've now fixed that.  Thanks.